# Convert argv and safe into tuple

Tags: c++, tuples, argv

is there a possibility to convert an char-array of arbitrary length in Integers and safe them into a tuple?

Here is an example:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  auto input = convert(argc, argv);
}
```

So if I call the main:

*./main 1 2*

```
input = std::tuple<int, int>(1, 2);
```

and:

*./main 2*

```
input = std::tuple<int>(2);
```

I hope you understand what I am looking for.

Comment: Not possible. Go get a time travel device - you want the type which must be known at compile-time to be influenced with values known later on at run-time.

Answer (score 4):

A dynamically sized tuple, with one type? What you're looking for is a `std::vector<int>`.

The number of elements in a tuple is fixed on compile time.

Comment: The problem is, that I have to use a tuple.

Comment: @wapitifass Are the sizes you're expecting constrained?

Comment: There'll be an upper limit. Maybe 5. But below every size should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I was not satisfied with the answers you received to this question so I have worked out a solution for you. This should not be taken as an indication that I agree that your idea is a good one :-)

The problem when converting dynamic data to static polymorphic functionality is that you must have a pre-built array of specialisations ready - one for each possibility in your runtime environment. It's the same problem that plagues double dispatch idioms.

Here is a minimal demonstration of a program that converts `argv` into an appropriate `tuple` and then calls a template function (templated on the template arguments of the tuple).

I have limited the number of arguments to 5 + the name of the program, but you could increase this limit by adding entries in the array `switch_functions`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


// this is a template of a function that does something with a tuple of strings of any size.
// it's left to the reader to figure out what to do with it.
template<class...Args>
void do_something_with_tuple(const std::tuple<Args...>& tuple)
{
    std::cout << "hello! " << sizeof...(Args) << std::endl;

}

// this is a type that manufactures a tuple of <size> strings
template<size_t size>
struct make_string_tuple
{
    using rest = typename make_string_tuple<size-1>::type;
    using mine = std::tuple<std::string>;
    using type = decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::declval<mine>(), std::declval<rest>()));

};

// this is the terminator specialisation that ends the sequence of strings in a tuple
template<>
struct make_string_tuple<0> {
    using type = std::tuple<>;
};

// this is a convenience typedef that obviates the use of the typename keyword
template<size_t size>
using make_string_tuple_t = typename make_string_tuple<size>::type;

// this is a function that initialises one element of a tuple from a corresponding position in a vector
template<size_t i, size_t n>
struct init_tuple{
    static void apply(make_string_tuple_t<n>& t, const std::vector<std::string>& x)
    {
        std::get<i>(t) = x[i];
        init_tuple<i+1, n>::apply(t, x);
    }
};

// this is the terminator specialisation for the above
template<size_t n>
struct init_tuple<n, n> {
    static void apply(make_string_tuple_t<n>& t, const std::vector<std::string>&)
    {

    }
};


// a template function that manufactures a tuple of size <size>, populates it from a vector
// which must be at least as large, and then calls the template function do_something_with_tuple
template<size_t size>
void call_it(const std::vector<std::string>& x)
{
    using tuple_type = make_string_tuple_t<size>;
    tuple_type t;
    init_tuple<0, size>::apply(t, x);
    do_something_with_tuple(t);
}

// a test program
auto main(int argc, char**argv) -> int
{
    // the type of function to call with a vector of arguments
    using switch_function = void (*)(const std::vector<std::string>&);

    // a vector of pointers to concrete versions of call_it
    static const switch_function switch_functions[] = {
        call_it<0>,
        call_it<1>,
        call_it<2>,
        call_it<3>,
        call_it<4>,
        call_it<5>,
        call_it<6>,
    };

    // convert argv into a vector of strings
    std::vector<std::string> x;
    while (argc--) {
        x.emplace_back(*argv++);
    }

    // call the appropriate version of call_it
    switch_functions[x.size()](x);


    return 0;
}
```